# Cash on delivery instruction field not showing in order details and order transactional emails

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-email, cash-on-delivery

I've typed in some text into instructions field of cash on delivery payment method. The issue is that the content of this text area is not showing in order details, on the payment information section.
Instructions are missing also in transactional order emails.
Anyone has never encountered this problem?
Which could be the cause of missing instruction text for cash on delivery default Magento module?
I'm using Magento 1.9.3.2, cash on delivery module has not been modified, it's default one.